# How to make dkms drivers build with kernels from kernel-ppa/mainline?

Tags: dkms

I need to use 5.4+ kernels because all official 5.3 kernels crash my system every day since the first 5.3 was released (almost a year ago).
But with these kernels running, the DKMS compiling of the Virtualbox drivers does not work. How can I make this work again?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds says

> Issues can occur installing an upstream kernel due to Virtualbox being
>   installed. For example:
>
> Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel:
>   3.7.0-030700rc2-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/make.log for more information.
>
> As per above, you need to either install the extra package, if
>   available, or uninstall virtualbox.

Do I need to download the kernel source? But where do I put it?

```
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack v5.4.17
```